# [Vue]Prevent focused input field's data being changed by upcoming new data?

Tags: vue.js, input, data-binding

at this moment I have a input field, let say it's being :value bind to a data called apiData,
which will be covered by new data from api call every 10s.

Is there any way to prevent my input field data being changed if the input field is being focused? Cos if i'm typing in the input field while new data returned, what I typed would be gone and covered by the new data.

The input field is

```
<input 
    v-on:keyup.enter="$event.target.blur()"
    @focus="$event.target.value=''"
    @blur="$event.target.value=oddsCell['odds']" 
    :value="oddsCell['odds']"
/>
```

Comment: Also, there're more than just one inputs, basically my api data is an array, and theres one input field for each of them

Comment: <input
              v-on:keyup.enter="$event.target.blur()"
              @focus="$event.target.value=''"
              @blur="$event.target.value=oddsCell['odds']"
              :value="oddsCell['odds']"
            />

the input field looks like this btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `@focus` event handlers to set a flag which indicates that the field is being edited right now and prevent the model variable from being overwritten. And the `@blur` event handler to reset the flag once editing is done.

Comment: hmm.. the thing is, I'd also need the value get overwritten as well, cos I would still need the correct new data, I just don't want it overwritten my input field value

Comment: I realize what you meant is something like this
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mXWELq
right? Set a flag to prevent new data overwritten the model variable, but then the data would never getting updated cause the data never get overwritten

Comment: i DO want the model variable being updated, but i do not want it overwritten the input field value while it's being focused

Comment: Then you might need to create a separate variable for your input data binding like you did in your codepen. And only sync that with the result from your API when you are not in the edit mode. It's a bit hard to tell without more context about what you're really doing with that data.